# Denying users in windows authentication IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm pretty new to .NET and I created a simple asp.net core web app using razor. I successfully published it in my IIS 8.5. I enabled windows authentication each time an user wants to access the page in my company network. However I'd like to restrict the access to all the users in the network except to a few users. I tried modifying my web.config file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authorization>
                <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Deny" users="*" />
                <add accessType="Allow" users="Alice,Bob" />
      </authorization>
          </security>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Autentificacion.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
      
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

After accessing the website the user is asked to put their windows user credentials but any user in the network can access the website not only Alice or Bob. Do I need to change an IIS configuration?

Comment: You already did. ASP.NET Core doesn't use `web.config`, what you did changed IIS configuration to block all users except Alice and Bob before the request reaches ASP.NET Core

Comment: As far as I know, the windows authentication will just check the the user is authenticated or not. It will not provide any role based control in the MVC application. To achieve role based authorize, you could try to use Policy-based authorization to authenticate only users from a Active Directory group have access to the page, please refer the following links: [Link 1](https://forums.asp.net/t/2152453.aspx) and [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61430368/asp-net-core-3-1-access-denied).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look into authorization Policies.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("NewPolicy", policy =>
                policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                    context.User.IsInRole("Some cool user group")));
        });
```

Where the users you want  to have access are a part of a user group called "Some cool user group".

From there you may protect  your routes and controllers with this policy by using the Authorize Attribute:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "NewPolicy")]
```

further reading:
https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-configuring-policy-based-authorization-with-blazor/

I would not recommend fiddling with the IIS web.config unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thank you this works for my app. But what if I wanted to specify an username in special that does not belong to any group? And Why is it not recommended to modify the web.config?

Comment: @AndresEspinel Messing with the IIS web.config can get a bit tricky and could accidentally mess up the entire server. Also authorization is better implemented at the application level, for various reasons. Anyways, yes you can absolutely look for specific users! The property you are looking for is context.User.Identity.Name :)